# File Access of any kind in Android SDK - Android Application

Tags: android, file-io

File Access in Android SDK.

I am trying ( and have been for a while ) to find a way to access any files within my android application. By file i mean: Random Access, Input, Output, Shared, Private, whatever kind of file.

There are no working examples online ( other than what the android sdk site claims to work ), and any attempt to try examples on Android SDK or any other website fail.

Can someone please give sample code from beginning to end showing a class which uses files in their android application. something that can write data as simple as an integer ( i don't care what it writes )

Comment: `and any attempt to try examples on Android SDK or any other website fail` --- can you please give some links which you followed and did not work? Because, even yesterday I implemented file reading writing in Android (following SDK API reference) and it worked!  Share the code you tried and failed.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I forgot that all example code from the Android examples has to be written in the Activity itself ( yes it does ).
In order to use the `openFileInput` method outside of the main Activity you must have a reference to the Activity Context which can be used in other classes with the import using:

```
import android.content.Context;
```

you must pass the Activity Context to another Context defined in that other class such as...

```
Context context;

public void passContext( Context cont ) {
    context = cont;
}
```

and then you can use context from the new class ( which referes to the resources available to the main `Activity` ) to access files and other resources.

HaHa hope this help anyone else.